# Can I reuse an invalidated iterator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, erase

The following code works (and admittedly is not the most efficient way to go about this routine). My question is this, is it discouraged to reuse the iterator as I have done here? Might it produce strange behavior? If so, why?

```
std::map<char, int> map;

map['a'] = 10;
map['b'] = 30;
map['c'] = 50;
map['d'] = 70;


std::map<char, int>::iterator iterator = map.begin();

for (; iterator != map.end(); iterator++) {
    if (iterator->second == 30 || iterator->second == 50) {
        map.erase(iterator);
        iterator = map.begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: If your compiler supports C++11, you can do `iterator = map.erase(iterator);` and avoid going over the same elements multiple times.

Comment: Yes that's fine. "Invalidated" means you cannot try to use the value stored in it; but you can set a new value.

Answer (score 3):

You're not using an invalidated iterator, but your logic is flawed. To fix it, make a small change to your code; only increment the iterator if you haven't erased an element during the current iteration. With your current code, assume that the first two elements in the `map` meet the erasure criterion. Then the second one will be left unerased because you increment past it on the second iteration through the loop.

```
for (; iterator != map.end();) {
    if (iterator->second == 30 || iterator->second == 50) {
        map.erase(iterator);
        iterator = map.begin();
    } else {
        ++iterator;
    }
}
```

If your compiler supports C++11 you can do this instead to erase elements from the `map`

```
for (; iterator != map.end(); ) {
    if (iterator->second == 30 || iterator->second == 50) {
        iterator = map.erase(iterator);
    } else {
        ++iterator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me double check then.

Comment: @chris It's an ordered container, `remove_if` won't be able to move elements to the end. Or at least that's what I've always thought. Can't say I've ever tried doing it myself.

Comment: @Praetorian: `remove_if` doesn't move elements to the end.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Huh? If it didn't, then the *erase-remove idiom* would be known as the *remove idiom* instead. If you meant it swaps the elements meeting the criterion with following elements that don't, then yes, I agree. It's not really moving elements to the end, but that's how I've always thought of it conceptually.

Comment: @Praetorian: The only elements that move are the ones not to be removed and they move toward the beginning of the range. The erase is still needed to remove the unspecified values at the end and set the physical size to match the new logical size.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is nothing wrong with re-assigning to the iterator and reusing it, because after the assignment operator is run, the old value is completely overwritten.

```
    iterator = map.begin();
```